# Sql server tuning advisor report

Tags: sql-server, performance

I created a trace file of a days work (~10 hours) at a client and ran it in the SQL Server tuning advisor.

The tuning advisor ran over the weekend and the report says:

Time taken for tuning: 2 days, 13 hours, 58 minutes
Number of events in workload: 1762519
Number of events tuned: 67525
Number of statements tuned: 37258

I also summed the "frequency" column in the tuning log to 141236 skipped events

Does this mean that the advisor only looked at 12%, (141236+67525)/1762519, of the workload file in 62 hours?

I.e. is the recommendation only based on the first hour of the workload?

Is there a way to speed up the analysis or do I need to run it for a month?

Answer (score 1):

No, the DTA has processed your entire workload file.

You need to identify why the DTA skipped 141236 events. This could be for a number of reasons, such as the queries reference very small tables i.e. smaller than 10 data pages or because the queries reference tables that have not been selected for tuning.

I suggest you review your tuning log and cross reference with the following microsoft documentation in order to identify why you events have been skipped.

[Troubleshooting the Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189239%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

In particular you will want to read:

- *Why Events are not Tuned*
- *Errors and Messages*

Comment: 141236 skipped events is ~9% of the workload. I am more concerned with the 88% that is neither skipped nor tuned.
(I know why the statements are skipped. Some are errors, other are cursor movements or small tables etc so that is ok.)